# Electron Forge with React doesn't render html success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-forge

I'm following this link
https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript

which is adding `React` into `Electron Forge` project.

The main codes are:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**renderer.ts**

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
const root = createRoot(rootElement)
root.render(<h2>Hello from React!</h2>)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

This is the error in Code:

[image]

when run `nom install`

```
ERROR in ./src/renderer.ts 47:34
Module parse failed: Unterminated regular expression (47:34)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| // root.render(<p>a</p>);
| const root = (0, client_1.createRoot)(document.body);
> root.render(Hello, from, React < /h2>););
|
ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts
./src/renderer.ts 53:22-26
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts(53,23)
      TS1005: ',' expected.
ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts
./src/renderer.ts 53:27-32
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts(53,28)
      TS1005: ',' expected.
ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts
./src/renderer.ts 53:35
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts(53,36)
      TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.
ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts
./src/renderer.ts 53:40
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/william/B/atplatform/src/renderer.ts(53,41)
      TS1005: ')' expected.
4 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
group_0 (webpack 5.89.0) compiled with 5 errors in 251 ms
```

Seems the import message is `root.render(Hello, from, React < /h2>););`
the html part was "transfer" to it then `render` comes the errors.

But not sure what was missing? Thanks!

Comment: You use JSX in a `.ts` file instead of `.tsx` and you probably haven't configured your project to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In the link it shows the file type is `.tsx`, but I added the code into `renderer.ts`, created a new file `test.tsx` works.

Thanks @Arkellys comment.

[image]